# Application hangs in hidden mode

Tags: c++, windows, task

I have one application. I am running it through task scheduler with logged on/off user and with highest privilege. I have logged messages in application at various places. But surprise to me that in normal way, application runs fine and messages are logged but through task with above options, applications hangs and no logs are written. I searched in google and found that with given conditions, task scheduler runs application in hidden mode. But still I need to figure out why application hangs and logs are not written.

Thanks

Comment: you don't provide enough information... what exactly does the application do ?

Comment: Its a project I am working on. It does encrypt/decrypt files.

Comment: and where do these files reside ? on a network share ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific "hidden mode", you are likely to have a bug in your application and you need to debug it just as any other deadlock - starting with a snapshot of the application in frozen state, and thread call stacks.

You normally attach to the application process with debugger, break execution and start checking it from there.

Comment: Roman, please check this. You will know if there is hidden mode or not.

Comment: Go to control panel, open task scheduler, create new task, go to general tab .. there at the bottom you will find check box "hidden". Which in given conditions automatically get checked. (For windows 7 only)

Comment: When you start it through a hidden task - eventually it is still a Windows process which you can attach debugger to and check your application state.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I am able to get debugger attached to it but no stack frame found :(.